# Styling ControlsFX Breadcrumb

Tags: css, javafx-8, breadcrumbs, controlsfx

I am using BreadcrumbBar from ControlsFX which works fine. The only problem i have is styling it to look like the image below. When using scenic view i saw that this component only has three classes `.bread-crumb-bar`, `.button`, `.first`. I tried adding border image like so, but did not appear.

```
/*
 * ControlFX bread crumb
 *   
 */
.bread-crumb-bar {
 }
.bread-crumb-bar .button {
  -fx-padding: 0 3 0 3;
  -fx-border-color: null;
  -fx-border-insets: 0;
  -fx-border-image-source: url("../images/icon/crumb-focused.png");
  -fx-border-image-slice: 1 10 1 10 fill;
  -fx-border-image-width: 1 10 1 10;
  -fx-border-image-repeat: stretch;
}

.bread-crumb-bar .button.first {
}
```

[image]

How can i style controlsfx breadcrumb to look like breadcrumb in the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how i have solved it very similar. For the slash you need the image.
You need to fiddle around with padding and set your font-family appropriately. Didnt find a selector for the last/selected crumb.

```
bread-crumb-bar {
     -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.bread-crumb-bar .button {
    -fx-padding: 8 12 8 20;
    -fx-border-color: null;
    -fx-border-insets: 0;
    -fx-content-display: left;
    -fx-background-position: left center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-image: url("../img/slash.png");
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-shape: null;
}
.bread-crumb-bar .first {
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-font-size: 1.11em;
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
    -fx-background-image: null;
    -fx-shape: null;
    -fx-padding: 8 12 8 0;
}
.crumb {
    -fx-text-fill: #000;
}
.crumb:hover,
.crumb:selected, 
.crumb:focused
{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -fx-border-color: null;
    -fx-font-size: 1.11em;
    -fx-text-fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```